# CoreLocation + A-GPS

Tags: swift, core-location

When setting `kCLLocationAccuracy` (`locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`), which method uses A-GPS to obtain the coordinates and which methods solely relies on GPS?

Is there a way to programmatically tell when the phone is/is not using A-GPS?

What output difference can one expect in the latitude and longitude when the `locationManager` is not making use of A-GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying technology used to get location fixes is hidden from you when you use CoreLocation. The docs I've read from Apple imply that it is always using a combination of GPS, cell tower triangulation, and WiFi location, so I suspect the answer is "always, if cell towers and or/geo-positioned WiFi stations are detected."

You can experiment with this by writing an app that logs the lat/long and "horizontal accuracy" readings, and the running the app as you turn WiFi and then cell service off.

Comment: What is meant by "horizontal accuracy"? Any reading I can do on that topic?

Comment: The location manager returns CLLocation objects. Take a look at the `CLLocation` class references in Xcode or online. It includes the horizontal accuracy field I was talking about.